# Magento Filter orders by state

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm trying to do exporting orders from magento store

```
 $myOrder=Mage::getModel('sales/order'); 
    $orders=Mage::getModel('sales/mysql4_order_collection');
    $allIds=$orders->getAllIds();
```

but it returns all orders to me. How can i filter orders by state "new"? i'm trying `$orders->addFieldToFilter('state',Array('eq'=>"new"));` or `$myOrder->setData('state','new');` but magento still returns all orders. Help

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('state', 'new'); // or 'status', 'pending'
$allIds = $orders->getAllIds();
```

Comment: I still find the whole state and status thing confusing like heck...

Comment: Yeah...it's kind of a 'grey area' for me also. What I found so far is that a 'state' can have more 'statuses'. The 'state' is used for internal processes and the status is used to display the info to the customer. But I may be wrong.

Comment: No, you are right. I just have to always look up which of the two is state and which is status. Not ideal naming (at least for me).

Comment: Just think of status as a frontend label for a state, that's it. States can have several statussus bound to them.